# I want to search a specific element of an array and if it exists to return its index

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an array of type Savings which contains a String (Name) and a double (Account Number). I want to search using an Account Number and see if it exist and then return all the  elements (Name + Account Number) and the Index of the Array that contain these elements. I tried this but it does not work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Savings[] ArrayOfSavings = new Savings[5];

        System.out.print("Enter Account Number: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double Ms = scan.nextDouble();

          //Loop until the length of the array
          for(int index = 0; index<= ArrayOfSavings.length;index++){

          if(ArrayOfSavings[index].equals(Ms)){

            //Print the index of the string on an array
            System.out.println("Found on index "+index);
             }
          }

        ArrayOfSavings[0] = new Savings("Giorgos",87654321);
        ArrayOfSavings[1] = new Savings("Panos",33667850);
    } 
}
```

/*Savings Class*/

public class Savings extends Generic {

```
public Savings(String FN, double AN) {

    super(FN, AN);
}

@Override
 public String toString(){
     return String.format("Customer: %s \n Acount Number: %.1f,
             getFirstName(),getAccNumber();
 }
```

}

Comment: And what's the problem? Do you know to use loops?

Comment: Show us the code behind the `Savings`-class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where you return -1 if it doesn't exist, or the index if you've found it. Just have to make sure you check for this case.

```
public static int findSavingsIfExists(double accountNumber, Savings[] allSavings) {
    for(int i = 0; i < allSavings.length(); i++) {
        if(allSavings[i].accountNumber == accountNumber) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and use it like so

```
int index = findSavingsIfExists(..., ArrayOfSavings);
if(index != -1) {
    Savings foundSavings = ArrayOfSavings[index];
} else {
    //Not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use somethig like this:

```
   double Ms = scan.nextDouble();
   int index = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfSavings.length; i++) {
    if (ArrayOfSavings[i].getAccountNumber == Ms ) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
  }

System.out.println(index);
```

Comment: Ammm... `(i < ArrayOfSavings.length) && (index == -1)` - what is it? Is it kind of joke? I mean, why not just `break`?